# Change value of input[type=time]?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change the value of an `input` with type `time` but I can't find a solution.

This is my attempt:

```
$("input").val("10.15");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bUYC6/

How can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you may know, you must provide a [*RFC3339*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) Standardised time format. Explained in the [**Internet Date/Time Formats**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6) Document Spec. So a clean input would be:

```
$("input").val( "18:01:07" );
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2btUd/

Although I believe you're trying to input a **secfrac** (A fraction of a second..) as explained in the above link, which you could apply:

```
<input type="time" value="" step="0.10" />
<script>
    $("input").val( "00:00:00.10" );
</script>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7eh93/

Which understandably isn't a clean method, but I don't think `<input type="time" />` is best worked with time-fractions.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$("#someid").val("10:15");
```

It work's fine here.